# I want to display 79 latlong on map with duplicate latlong also

Tags: javascript

```
function initialize() 
{
    var demoCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(21.1500, 79.0900);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('world-map'), {
        zoom : 5,
        center : demoCenter,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

}


function showPointonMap(latlong) {

    for (var temp = 0; temp < latlong.length; temp++) {

        var result_lat_long = latlong[temp].split(',');
        var latitude = result_lat_long[0];
        var longitude = result_lat_long[1];
        var latlng=new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position : new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),

            position:latlng,
            map : map,
            id : temp,

        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

        });
    }


}
```

I have 79 latitude and longitude values,but same latitude and longitude are overlapped each other and not displayed.I want to show all latitude and longitude with duplicates on map.

Comment: please suggest if anybody knows the solution..

Answer (score 0):

```
for (temp=0; temp <latlong.length; temp++) { 
            var result_lat_long = latlong[temp].split(',');
            var latitude = result_lat_long[0];
            var longitude = result_lat_long[1];

            //update the position of the coincident marker by applying a small multipler to its coordinates
            var newLat = latitude -(Math.random()-.5);
            var newLng = longitude -(Math.random()-.5);

            var  finalLatLng= new google.maps.LatLng(newLat,newLng);
```

Run the program by using this code.